# Nginx clean urls, how to rewrite a folder as an argument with try_files

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, uri

I'm writing a simple CMS in PHP. Pages (markdown files) and images are accessed like this (respectively):

```
example.org/?q=about.md
example.org/?i=photo.jpg
```

Optionally, I would like to use clean URLs with Nginx, to make the same requests look like this:

```
example.org/about
example.org/photo.jpg
```

I rather use `try_files` than `if` and `rewrite` but after experimenting for hours, I can't get it to work.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /?q=$uri.md =404;
}

location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
    try_files $uri /?i=$uri =404;
}
```

I don't understand why the above code doesn't work (urls with argument work fine but the pretty ones give 404 errors).

Is there something wrong with passing the folder name as an argument using `$uri`?
Do I need to escape some weird characters (apart from my landlord)?

---

To be thorough, I'm running Nginx 1.6.2, using the standard nginx.conf.
Here's the rest of my server block:

```
server_name example.org;
root /srv/example/;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

(...)

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;    
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

and fastcgi.conf is also standard.

Comment: Is `document_root` set correctly? You could try `/index.php?q=$uri.md` in the `try_files`, i.e. explicitly state the `index.php`, although I think it should work like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `document_root` is okay since the regular/long urls work fine. I have also tried with `/index.php?q=$uri.md` but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your example to work by simply omitting the `=404`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /?q=$uri.md;
}

location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
    try_files $uri /?i=$uri;
}
```

Quoting [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

> Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; [...] **If none of the files were found**, an internal redirect to the `uri` specified in the last parameter is made.

You want that internal redirect, which is only happening if none of the files are found, but `=404` is always found.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly now! And re-reading your answer, I even understand the logic behind it. Thanks